# Comparison test involiving e

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just one thing: with each sum can I compare
$$a_{n}=e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$$
to prove that the series
$$\sum a_{n}$$
diverges?

Comment: First find out the asymptotic behaviour of $a_n$. That will make it clear with what to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e-\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)\sim_\infty e-\exp\left(n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\right)\right)=e-e\exp\left(-\frac1{2n^2}\right)\\\sim_\infty e-e\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\frac e{2n}$$
so the given series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series $\frac e2\sum\limits_n\frac1n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what $\sim_{\infty}$ means?